# Setting up Passenger + Nginx on Arch

Tags: linux, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, arch-linux

I'm trying to setup passenger and nginx on Arch, but I can't seem to get the nginx server to even start.

I've followed the guide found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#Ruby_Integration_.28Ruby_on_Rails_and_Rack-based.29 under option A using the ruby gems to do the installation. I have nginx installed in the /opt/nginx/ directory.

I've symbolically linked /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx to /usr/bin/nginx and added the init script found at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx/Init_script. I've also changed the permissions to 755 and it is owned by root as suggested.

I get the following error though when I run `sudo /etc/rc.d/nginx start`

```
/etc/rc.d/nginx: line 5: /etc/conf.d/nginx: No such file or directory
:: Checking configuration
[BUSY] nginx: [crit] pread() "/opt/nginx/" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx: configuration file /opt/nginx/ test failed
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/etc/rc.d/nginx: line 5: /etc/conf.d/nginx: No such file or directory
:: Checking Configuration
[BUSY] nginx: [crit] pread() "/opt/nginx/" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx: configuration file /opt/nginx/ test failed
```

It means that:

- the `/etc/conf.d/nginx` file doesn't exist. Just create it or comment
  out the below line in init script:

  `. /etc/conf.d/nginx`
- you set the wrong configuration file: `/opt/nginx/` is a directory which you specify for `--prefix` when compiling. Maybe `/opt/nginx/etc/nginx.conf`.

Comment: What does /etc/conf.d/nginx do or rather should do? I ended up getting it working using what you told me and copying this in and making minor changes to it. http://www.sk3tchy.com/archlinux-passenger-install-nginx-module-rc-d-dameon/

Comment: It is the config file to define NGINX_CONFIG, NGINX_PID, ... (same with `/etc/sysconfig/...` in the Red Hat based)